# About Unity Abstract Class Susbscribe an Action

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, abstract, invoke

I'm having a problem when subscribing an abstract class to an action in Unity. When I invoke the action, it sometimes executes more than once. However, when I subscribe a subclass to the action, it works correctly. What could be the reason for this?
This issue occurs when the user watches an ad and earns a reward.

I'm using Unity 2021.3.19.f1 LTS
Android platform

Here is my code:

SRTAdManager.cs

```
public class SRTAdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    
void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else {
             Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
    ...
    public event Action<string> onAdReward;
    public void UserEarnedReward(string rewardType)
    {
        onAdReward?.Invoke(rewardType);
    }
    ...
}
```

SRTAdmobAdManager.cs

```
public class SRTAdmobAdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    public void ShowAdmobRewarded(string userReward)
    {
        if (IsRewardedLoaded())
        {
            this.userReward = userReward;
            this.rewardedAd.Show();
        }
        else {
            LoadAdmobRewarded();
        }
    }

    public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        SRTAdManager.instance.UserEarnedReward(userReward);
    }
    ...
}
```

RideUIManager.cs

```
public abstract class RideUIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    protected virtual void OnEnable()
    {
        SRTAdManager.instance.onAdReward += OnReward;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        SRTAdManager.instance.onAdReward -= OnReward;
    }
    public abstract void OnReward(string rewardType);
    ...
}
```

AdvancedRideUIManager

```
public class AdvancedRideUIManager : RideUIManager
{

    protected override void OnEnable()
    {
        base.OnEnable();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    public override void OnReward(string rewardType)
    {
        if (rewardType.Equals("MoneyBonusADV"))
        {
                reward *= 2;
                doubleItButton.SetActive(false);
                rewardText.text = reward.ToString();
        }
        if (rewardType.Equals("BonusTimeADV"))
        {
                loseModalWindowManager.ModalWindowOut();
                advancedRide.advancedRide.remaningTime = rewardInfo.bonusTime;
                advancedRide.hasTime = true;
                advancedRide.enumared = false;
                GameEventManager.GameEventPost(
                    "Bonus Time"
                );
                SetAudio(false);
                Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method corresponding to `OnEnable` is `OnDisable`.

Comment: should i call SRTAdManager.instance.onAdReward -= OnReward; in `OnDisable` not in `OnDestroy`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is the reason, but it's worth a try.